# class instances usage in web application in python

Tags: python, class, plotly-dash

I am writing Plotly Dash app. I'm not good enough on web programming and have some troubles in understanding. I have two classes. One is my own class so called `DataHandler`, another is `Dash` app. Web app initiation is performed as this:

```
import dash
from own_data_handler import DataHandler

# code 

app = dash.Dash(__name__, title='title', external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
data_handler = DataHandler()

# code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The question is how these class instances are manipulated? Will every user create it's own instance or data will be mixed between different users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current code, one instance of the `DataHandler` class will be created per server instance. As a side note, the `DataHandler` must be ready only when you create in the global scope. Manipulating its state by users can lead to inconsistencies, see more details in the [documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/sharing-data-between-callbacks).

Comment: Will it help preserving consistency if I create `DataHandler` instance within some `Div` and call class methods inside callbacks?

Comment: Yes, as long as you store the state on the client, e.g. in a hidden `Div` or a `Store`  component, it will work. Note that the data (e.g. your `DataHandler`  class) must be JSON serializable, as it is exchanged between server/client during the callback.